# Use of a/an with abbreviations

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

Say we have an acronym or abbreviation like SSH (Secure Shell). What is the correct form of the following phrase?
1) An SSH console
2) A SSH console

I tend to use the first because it "sounds" right. However, a reader of the phrase could expand the abbreviation and read "an secure shell" which obviously sounds wrong!
Is there a definite rule for this or the choice is made based on the sound of the phrase?

Comment: Both are acceptable. Check this out: http://goo.gl/U2bty8. I personally read *A SSH console* "a secure shell console". (Yet, sometimes I read SSH as "es-es-aytch".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'en' MBBS doctor is how we *pronounce*.

So, it's...

> An SSH console

The rule remains the same *(whether it is an acronym, a full word or even a spelled number)* that if a word is 'sounding like vowel', it'll take an indefinite article 'an' (as in 'an hour').

Comment: Thank you for the answer Maulik. What do you think about the comment posted to the question?

Comment: Even ['loose weight' has some results on Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lose+weight%2C+loose+weight&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Close%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLose%20Weight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cloose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bloose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLoose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLoose%20Weight%3B%2Cc0)! **So,** I'll stick to basics!

Answer (score 3):

According to:

- [APA Style](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/04/using-a-or-an-with-acronyms-and-abbreviations.html)
- [Ontario Training Network](https://ontariotraining.net/grammar-tip-a-or-an-with-acronyms/)
- [Shearson Editorial Services](https://www.shearsoneditorial.com/2013/07/a-or-an-with-abbreviations-it-depends/)
- [American Journal Experts](https://www.aje.com/en/arc/editing-tip-indefinite-article-use-abbreviations/)
- [Grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/a-vs-an-when-to-use/)

An acronym is an abbreviation you can pronounce as an actual word. Initialisms are abbreviations that you pronounce as a string of letters. Whether it's an abreviation or initialism is an unnecessary distinction for application of the rule, but it affects the phonetization.

The use of "**a**" versus "**an**" with an abreviation or initialism is determined by two things:

1. Is the abbreviation pronounced letter by letter or as a word
2. Is the first ***sound*** a [vowel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vowel) or a [consonant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consonant) - silent letters aren't considered

Examples:

- a [FASB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Accounting_Standards_Board#Conceptual_Framework) rule - A Financial Accounting Standards Board rule.
- a [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) schematic - A local area network.
- a [MOMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_Modern_Art) exhibit - A Museum of Modern Art exhibit.
- a [NICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neonatal_intensive_care_unit) nurse - A neonatal intensive care unit nurse.
- a [SAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-to-air_missile) base - A surface-to-air missile base.
- an [FOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_operating_base) airfield - A forward operating base airfield.
- an [LAPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_Police_Department) memo - A Los Angeles Police Department memo.
- an [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) test - A magnetic resonance imaging test.
- an [NPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_by_mouth) order - A nothing by mouth (Latin: nil per os) order.
- an [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT) exam - A Scholastic Assessment Test exam.

See also: The [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) (IPA).